# how to build singularity container from dockerfile

Tags: docker, singularity-container

I want to build singularity container from dockerfile.

I have pulled and run docker images from docker hub with singularity.

```
singularity pull docker://ubuntu:latest
```

I  have also build the image from singularity recipe file.

```
singularity build  cpp.sif singularity_file
```

But I want to build singularity image from dockerfile.

Anyone know how to do it. Is it possible ???

Comment: Looks like all the accepted solutions uses docker. Is there a way to build the singularity container directly from the dockerfile without calling docker? Only singularity?

Comment: @Soerendip did you check my answer

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You cannot build a singularity container *directly* from a Dockerfile, but you can do it in a two-step process.

```
docker build -t local/my_container:latest .
sudo singularity build my_container.sif docker-daemon://local/my_container:latest
```

Using `docker://my_container` looks for the container on Docker Hub. When you use `docker-daemon`, it looks at your locally built docker containers. You can also use `Bootstrap: docker-daemon` in a Singularity definition file.

---

*EDIT:* Both singularity and apptainer now require an explicit tag name for the source docker container. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: I think this is the only way to do it.

Comment: Doesn''t work in apptainer. `FATAL:   While performing build: conveyor failed to get: invalid image source: invalid reference format`.

Comment: `docker-daemon://local/my_container` didn't work on my local images.

Answer (score 22):

You can transform a Dockerfile into a singularity recipe (or vise-versa) using Singularity Python. Singularity Python offers some very helpful utilities, consider to install it if you plan to work with singularity a lot

```
pip3 install spython # if you do not have spython install it from the command line

# print in the console
spython recipe Dockerfile

# save in the *.def file
spython recipe Dockerfile > Singularity.def
```

If you have problems with pip you can download spython or pull a container as described in [Singularity Python install](https://singularityhub.github.io/singularity-cli/install). Find more about recipe conversion  [here](https://singularityhub.github.io/singularity-cli/recipes)

Comment: I would recommend using ">" and not "&>" as "&>" will also write warnings into the output file, which will then of course result in parsing errors when you try to use it.

Answer (score -7):

```
sudo singularity build ubuntu.sif docker://ubuntu:latest
```

builds it directly for me

Unsure if there was an update to singularity for this purpose

Comment: This command  is building it from a docker image and not from a Dockerfile