# Porting docker build commands to Singularity

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, singularity-container

```
    docker build \
    --tag gcr.io/fuzzbench/runners/afl/libpng-1.2.56-intermediate \
    --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 \
    --cache-from gcr.io/fuzzbench/runners/afl/libpng-1.2.56-intermediate \
    --file fuzzers/afl/runner.Dockerfile \
    fuzzers/afl
```

I want to port this to a Singularity build command. (Singularity does not support tag/build-arg/etc.)
Also on a separate issue, in my Dockerfiles I have ARG, and spython says **WARNING ARG is not supported for Singularity, and must be defined with a default to be parsed.** , and there is really little documentation on how to port from Docker to Singularity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to "port" a Docker image to Singularity is to [build the Singularity image directly from the Docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60314664/how-to-build-singularity-container-from-dockerfile/60316979#60316979): `singularity build libpng_1.2.56.sif docker://gcr.io/fuzzbench/runners/afl/libpng-1.2.56-intermediate`. If the source docker image has been built locally and is not in a remote registry use `docker-daemon://` instead of `docker://`.

The documentation also has a pretty sizable [Singularity and Docker](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.7/user-guide/singularity_and_docker.html) section that goes over using Docker images with Singularity and similarities/differences between a `Singularity` definition file and a `Dockerfile`.

If you want to maintain separate `Dockerfile` and `Singularity` files for creating images, keep in mind there is not always a direct equivalent. *e.g,.* `--tag` in Docker is effectively equivalent to the filename of the Singularity image, buildkit settings are specific to the Docker build process and do not have a counterpart in Singularity.