# Is it possible to create a Singularity image from Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, singularity-container

I have Singularity installed. In my repo I have Dockerfile. I want to create a SIF (Singularity Image) from that Dockerfile. I tried to look the docs and check the `docker build` option but it does not contain an option for Dockerfile. Is it possible to create a SIF image from Dockerfile? Something like:

```
Singularity build test.sif Dockerfile
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to build singularity container from dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60314664/how-to-build-singularity-container-from-dockerfile)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot build a singularity image from a dockerfile. But you can build a docker image from the dockerfile and then convert that docker image to singularity format.

```
docker build -t myimg:latest .
sudo singularity build img.sif docker-daemon://myimg:latest
```